# How to get data efficiently from the more than one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wants data from all table using single query. how i can get data from this table efficiently

[image: this is my database tables]

Below is my expected output: 
[image]

I have tried like this nd giving error.

```
select b_id,
b_datetime,
invoice_id,
plan_id,
exp_datetime,
plan_name,
plan_amount,
months,
s_name,
s_url,
name
amount 
from tblplanboughts pb,tblplans p , tblshops s , tblusers u 
where pb.uid=u.uid && 
pb.plan_id=p.plan_id && u.uid=s.uid;
```

Comment: How do you create your output right now? What have you tried? What part of it did not work? Google sql join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, in MySQL we can use [`AND` and `&&`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) also.. :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I don't have in-depth knowledge, but I tried and its working! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [Inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) will solve your problem:

```
select pb.b_datetime, pb.invoice_id, p.plan_name, p.months, pb.amount, s.s_name, s.s_url, u.name, pb.exp_datetime
from tblplanboughts pb, tblpricingplans p, tblshops s, tblusers u
where pn.b_id=s.b_id and pb.plan_id=p.plan_id and pb.uid=u.uid
```

*Or* use Inner join with Join keyword

```
select pb.b_datetime, pb.invoice_id, p.plan_name, p.months, pb.amount, s.s_name, s.s_url, u.name, pb.exp_datetime
from tblplanboughts pb inner join tblpricingplans p on pb.plan_id=p.plan_id
                       inner join tblshops s on pb.b_id=s.b_id
                       inner join tblusers u on pb.uid=u.uid
```

Comment: With the possible exception of CROSS JOINs, I think we should discourage the use of implicit joins wherever we can.

Comment: Strawberry thanks for suggestion..I edited my question whatever i tried and also mentioned the reason where i was stuck.

Comment: @Strawberry: even for cross joins I think using an explicit `CROSS JOIN` is better, because it documents that you really intend to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use aliasing in From clause then apply join on relation fields between tables :

```
select pb.*, p.* , s.* , u.*

from tblplanboughts pb, tblpricingplans p, tblshops s, tblusers u

where pn.b_id=s.b_id and pb.plan_id=p.plan_id and pb.uid=u.uid
```

you can also use `inner join...on` statement instead of use (=) in where clause